# php remove the value from array

Tags: php, arrays

need help replacing array value
 i`m trying check experience and space exists in the below array and  replace space with experience max (i,e next array values if its equal null/space replace with experience max),
i have pasted code below  which im using to find and replace array value, its replacing the experience to experience max instead of empty to experience max

```
array[1] => name,
array[2] => Work Experience,
array[3] => ,
array[4] => company,
array[5] => location
```

o/p :

```
array[1] => name,
array[2] => Work Experience,
array[3] => Work Experience Max,
array[4] => company,
array[5] => location

$search = "Work Experience";
foreach ($val as $key=> $cnt) {
    // echo "inside foreach ".$cnt;
    if ($cnt == $search) {
        echo  $keyvalue = $key;
        break;
    }
}
if (isset($keyvalue)) {
    $firstarryval = array_splice($val, $keyvalue, 1);
}

if ($firstarryval == '') {
    array_splice($val, $keyvalue, 0, "Work Experience Max");
} else {
    array_splice($val, $keyvalue, 0, "Work Experience Max");
}
```

Comment: what's the desired output look like?

Comment: @Dagon array[1] =>name,
array[2] =>Work Experience,
array[3]=>Work Experience Max,
array[4]=>company,
array[5[=>location

Comment: that's what you already have above

Comment: If it is not intended to be an array of labels, then you can try to check also this [example](http://codepad.org/ppVY8yqP) (btw, a bit better to test emptyiness with the empty() function)

Comment: @Dagon  current output is array[1] =>name,
    array[2] =>Work Experience Max,
    array[3]=>,
    array[4]=>company,
    array[5[=>location

Comment: @Stano .i`m trying to search a values and next array values of the search value , if next array values is empty im trying  replacing value

Comment: @user1510536 Made also a simple form example. See it [here](http://pastebin.com/4SFcKUHf).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here is the solution explained:

```php
$arr = array( 0=>'name', 1=>'Work Experience', 2=>'', 3=>'company', 4=>'location' );
var_export($arr); echo '<br/>';
$search = "Work Experience";
$arrkey = false;
foreach($arr as $key=>$value){ // set variables and advance internal pointer
    echo "inside foreach $key => $value <br/>";
    if( $value == $search ) {
        echo $key;
        echo $arrkey = key($arr); // internal php pointer already points to next array key
        break;
    }
}
if ($arrkey!=false && empty($arr[$arrkey])) {
    $arr[$arrkey] = 'Work Experience Max';
}
echo '<br/>'; var_export($arr);
```

Useful links: [foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php), [key](http://php.net/manual/en/function.key.php), [empty](http://sk.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php). Hope it will help! :-)